# $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k!}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, factorial, sumset

I'm presented with the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k!}{n!}$

I've got a hunch that it diverges to infinity but I wasn't able the prove that the sum is superior to a series diverging to infinity.

I would like a hint about how I should start.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does not diverge to infinity.  There are $n$ terms.  All but the last are less than $\frac 1n$, so the sum is less than $\frac {n-1}n+1 \lt 2$

Comment: Yes thank you, and what about the lower bound?

Comment: The last term is $1$, so that is a lower bound to the sum.  Have you tried computing the values of the sum in a spreadsheet for $n$ from $1$ to $10$ or so?  That might give some inspiration.

Answer (score 5):

For any $n\geq 3$
$$\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k! = 1+\frac{1}{n}+\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{n(n-1)}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n!}\right)}_{(n-2)\text{ terms bounded by }\frac{1}{n(n-1)}}\leq 1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{n-2}{n(n-1)}$$
is $1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$, hence the limit of the LHS as $n\to +\infty$ is simply $\color{red}{\large 1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the upper bound: For large $n,$

$$n! + (n-1)! + (n-2)! + \cdots + 1! < n! + (n-1)(n-1)!.$$